# Bug with square screen capture in Lion OS X

Tags: macos, screen-capture, bug

I have noticed an annoying bug in OS X Lion that happens if you try to take a screen cap with cmd+shift+4. It works fine with every rectangular selection, but if you take a square shot (for example 150x150 or 280x280...) it captures 1 pixel in excess only in width: so, a 150x150 will eventually become a 151x150, forcing me to crop it.

I was wondering if it's just me or if it's a known bug.

Comment: How are you sure your selection is a perfect square?

Answer (score 2):

I tried it in Lion 10.7.1 and can't confirm that issue. Creating two screen shoots (150x150 and 637x637) and both did have the expected size. Checked it with the Preview application.

Do you use a mouse or a touch pad? I find it rather challenging creating a square selection by using the Magic Trackpad. Especially since the size of the selection disappears after a second or so and is replaced by the absolut coordinates.

Comment: Also confirmed I can't reproduce this problem. I marked off a 150 x 150 area of my screen and the resulting PNG was exactly 150 x 150 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

It's you (or at least your mouse settings are making it hard on you) :-)

It isn't so much a bug as its hard to have one-pixel fine control when also releasing the mouse. The dexterity required to get it right each and every time is high unless you are using the lowest levels of mouse tracking.

The Skitch program is free on the app store and has better guides to restrict your snap canvas, easily resize the snap if you get too much and a host of other advanced editing tools.